# Why does Swagger UI POST form data with Content-Type: undefined?

Tags: swagger-ui

I'm trying to POST form data using Swagger UI, but the request is sent with `Content-Type: undefined`:

[image]

How can I configure it so it works? JSON POST works just fine.

Here is my API definition:

```js
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "V1",
    "title": "Title"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/api/getcalculation": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "ArrearsOfPay"
        ],
        "operationId": "ApiArrearsOfPayPost",
        "consumes": [],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "InsolvencyDate",
            "in": "formData",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
          },
          {
            "name": "DismissalDate",
            "in": "formData",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
          },
          {
            "name": "UnpaidPeriodFrom",
            "in": "formData",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
          },
          {
            "name": "UnpaidPeriodTo",
            "in": "formData",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
          },
          {
            "name": "ApClaimAmount",
            "in": "formData",
            "required": false,
            "type": "number",
            "format": "double"
          },
          {
            "name": "PayDay",
            "in": "formData",
            "required": false,
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          },
          {
            "name": "ShifPattern",
            "in": "formData",
            "required": true,
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "collectionFormat": "multi"
          },
          {
            "name": "WeeklyWage",
            "in": "formData",
            "required": false,
            "type": "number",
            "format": "double"
          },
          {
            "name": "StatutaryMax",
            "in": "formData",
            "required": false,
            "type": "number",
            "format": "double"
          },
          {
            "name": "NumberOfDaysWorkedInWeek",
            "in": "formData",
            "required": false,
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/ArrearsOfPayCalculationResponseModel"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "ArrearsOfPayCalculationResponseModel": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "startOfPayWeek": {
          "format": "date-time",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "maximumLiability": {
          "format": "double",
          "type": "number"
        },
        "employerLiability": {
          "format": "double",
          "type": "number"
        },
        "minimumLiability": {
          "format": "double",
          "type": "number"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your API definition (JSON/YAML).

Comment: @Helen when I copy the curl command and set application/x-www-form-urlencoded as content type the post method workd just fine and model binding with fromForm works as expected. I am unsure why Swagger is not seeting the contenty type.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
"consumes": []
```

The `consumes` keyword specifies the `Content-Type` header in requests. Since you are POSTing form data, it should be:

```
"consumes": ["application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
```

Tip: You can paste your spec into http://editor.swagger.io to check for syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks for quick response , I have added annotation  [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")] on my post method and tried again. But in produced Json Consumes is still "consumes": [] , Any idea why the value is not set although solution complies OK without complaints?

Comment: @Mir Which language/framework are you using to generate the API definition?

Comment: ASP.Net Core 2- language is C#

Comment: @Mir Since you are generating the API definition and not writing it manually, I'd suggest [asking a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=How+to+specify+%60consumes%60+for+form+data+in+.....+(Swashbuckle+%2F+Swagger-Net+%2F+insert+yours)+%3F) specifically about your framework (Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, etc.)